# How to install / use Prolog on Mac Monterey

Tags: macos, prolog, editor, swi-prolog

I have xQuartz installed as I use VSCode to code with c++. I am a bloody beginner and have absolutely no clue how to use SWI Prolog with the built in editor on my Mac. Or VSCode as an editor.
None of the questions posted here previously help me as I don't understand any of the instructions given.
Could someone tell me what to do in the easiest way possible? I have never used the terminal to install things so should you give me instructions, make these fool proof.
I got as far as downloading SWI Prolog from the website and dragging it into my applications folder. It opens [as seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhOoz.png). What else do I need to do? I would ideally have the same editor that is being used [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLPhh.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Page https://www.swi-prolog.org/IDE.html says:

> SWI-Prolog Editor (Windows)
>
> Gerhard Röhner has developed an integrated Prolog editor in MS-Windows following the conventions of this platform. The embedded SWI-Prolog provides functionality similar to swipl-win.exe, including the possibility to run XPCE GUI programs.

And the [linked website](https://arbeitsplattform.bildung.hessen.de/fach/informatik/swiprolog/indexe.html) has this image:

[image: Screenshot of SWI-Prolog-Editor website]

That suggests there is no macOS version of the program you want to run, and you would need [a way to run Windows software on a Mac](https://www.howtogeek.com/187359/5-ways-to-run-windows-software-on-a-mac/).

On Windows, I get "Prolog" and "SWI Prolog" as different menu items, and SWI Prolog gives me the same kind of terminal screen you see, but "Prolog" gives me a GUI editor environment. Quite plain, but more features than the terminal. Maybe there is similar on your Mac install?

https://swish.swi-prolog.org/ is an online editor for SWI Prolog which is good for testing small code.